# Odoo 12: I can't filtered tree view with domain

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I want to return a filtered view with the domain but the domain is not taken. When I set an integer value, the domain is taken. But when I want to get the id of the logged in user, it returns nothing.

This is my code:

```
@api.multi
def filtrer_les_rdv(self):
    user = self.env['res.users'].sudo().search([('id','=',self.env.uid)]).id
    return{
        'name': 'Mes rendez-vous',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'rdv.rdv',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'domain': [('id_of_student','=',user)],
        'view_id': self.env.ref('rdv.mes_rdv_tree_view').id,
        'target': 'current'
    }
```

When I replace **user** by an integer all things work.

This is my XML code:

```
<record id="action_server_flitrer_mes_rdv" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Mes rendez-vous</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_rdv_rdv"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
      action = model.filtrer_les_rdv()
    </field>
</record>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `self.env['res.users'].sudo().search([('id','=',self.env.uid)]).id == self.env.uid == self.env.user.id`, basically you are retrieving the same value by the search method, you could just used `[('id_of_student','=', self.env.user.id)]`. what do you want to filter exactly?  The action is not showing any record because the domain used is not what you expected, could you explain what record you want to see?